# CentOS 7 (dracut) is finding inconsistent network device names causing problems for kickstart

Tags: centos, centos7, rhel7, initramfs, dracut

I use the boot options `biosdevname=1 net.ifnames=1` in order to get consistent, predictable device names. I'm starting to notice a problem where in some cases, the network device names are not consistent. For example, if I drop to a dracut debug shell and look at the output of rdsosreport.txt, I see this:

```
+ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: p3p1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a8:b4:56:50:97:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a8:b4:56:50:97:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Notice that there is a mix of consistent (p3p1) and legacy style (eth1) naming. However, if I look at the the interfaces from the dracut debug shell, I see this:

```
initqueue:/run/initramfs# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: p3p1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a8:b4:56:50:97:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: p3p2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a8:b4:56:50:97:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

p3p1/p3p2 are the correct expected names. For some reason, early in the initrd sequence, they are coming up in the mixed format. My assumption is that there is some sort of race going on here and given a bit more time, it (udev?) settles into the correct state, but I'm not sure exactly where it is. Unfortunately, this is causing problems for some of our automated server builds, because servers are coming up after (postinstall) first-boot and trying to bring up `eth1` when the real interface name is `p3p2`.

I've been digging through the dracut modules to try and figure out where the problem may lie, but haven't been able to determine it conclusively yet, so looking for suggestions.

Also, this behavior doesn't happen all the time. The same server, booting the same image sometimes works fine, and other times gets this mixed naming behavior. Which also sort of tells me this is some kind of race - sometimes the race is won, and sometimes it is lost.

Comment: Are the names correct when the installed system boots?

Comment: @MichaelHampton no. The installed system will end up with config files `ifcfg-p3p1` and `ifcfg-eth1`, but eth1 will not exist. So, to get the installed system working normally, I need to edit the network configs by-hand.

Also, I just appended to my original post - the behavior is inconsistent, meaning sometimes the problem happens, and sometimes it doesn't. Which tells me, race.

Comment: It seems that by the time you get past the initramfs and into the installer, the device names should have long since settled, far in advance of anything you might be doing in the kickstart. Can you be specific about what you are doing that results in this failed network configuration?

Comment: Yeah, I use a custom-built initramfs, that dynamically configures LACP bonding. We have some single-homed hosts, some dual-homed, and some with multiple interfaces that get aggregated into a single bond. It "usually" works, except for when this problem occurs.

Comment: This custom stuff is written as a dracut module? These should load long after the udev names have settled. Also be aware that dracut can set up bonding itself given a command line option to do so.

Comment: We've made modifications to the `40network` dracut modules for our custom needs.

Comment: I think the race problem may be due to biosdevname. So far, I haven't been able to reproduce the problem when using `biosdevname=0 net.ifnames=1`, which might be an option for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here. It turns out, the problem was (partially) self-inflicted.

The part we can't control:

Using boot option `biosdevname=1` has the potential to cause races during the interface renaming phase. If you can live without it, simply using `net.ifnames=1 biosdevname=0` might be preferable, even if the resulting names are "less pretty".

The part we CAN control:

Our site uses a custom modified dracut `40network` module. One of the main things our version does is that it probes the contents of `/sys/class/net/` looking for viable interfaces to automatically add to a bond. (we don't always know the device names in advance, which is why the module needed some logic to identify them on its own). The race mentioned above can cause a delay in the renaming of files in `/sys/class/net/`. The solution was simple: add a 5 second sleep to the script prior to probing `/sys/class/net/`. This gives `biosdevname` (hopefully more than enough) time to finish renaming devices. Testing so far seems A-OK.

Comment: Interesting. What names do you get with `biosdevname=0`? It's been probably a year since I upgraded the last CentOS 7 box I had (to 8).

Comment: With `net.ifnames=1 biosdevname=1`, we get names like "p3p1", "p3p2" (slot and port, pretty simple). With `net.ifnames=1 biosdevname=0`, those names change to things like "enp193s0f0", "enp193s0f1".

Comment: Ah, so the normal names come back when you use `biosdevname=0`. Probably best to switch back to that as it's what everyone else is using. Those old names were largely abandoned years ago.

Comment: I know the legacy "eth0", "eth1" names were abandoned, for good reason. `biosdevname=1` is actually the default behavior on Dell hardware, unless explicitly disabled.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the Dell `biosdevname=1` names were abandoned. With this set to 0, device names use the same general formats across all hardware vendors.